# Click TextView inside linear layout inside ScrollLayout

Tags: android, layout

this below code for my login_activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundLogin"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fillViewport="false">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"

            android:paddingBottom="20dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/login"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:id="@+id/email_edit_text"

            android:hint="@string/email_address_string" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:id="@+id/password_edit_text"

            android:hint="@string/password_string" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:text="@string/login_string"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/login_button" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="@string/need_an_account"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textStyle="italic"

            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/need_an_account" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I want to click on TextView id=need_an_account that like below:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.need_an_account:
            // some code
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Note that i don't want to use findViewById() method
But onClick not Working at all how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You have to specify on click listener on TextView

Comment: @LalitJadav as i sey a want to use Implement of onClickListener

Comment: if you dont like to deal with findViewById i suggest you look at butterknife http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: @LalitJadav whay onClick not Working????!!!?????!!!!

Comment: @komeilshahmoradi You have to specify for which view you have assigned listner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `OnClickListener`, Here is an alternative -

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
  android:text="@string/need_an_account"
  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
  android:textStyle="italic"
  android:onClick="myTextViewMethod"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:id="@+id/need_an_account" />
```

Now write `myTextViewMethod`in you `Activity`

```
public void myTextViewMethod(View v) {
   // Do your stuff here...
}
```

Plus point, No need to implement `OnClickListener`, Android will do it in background.

And if you wanna use an Interface `View.OnClickListener`
Simple, set `need_an_account.setOnClickListener(this);`

Answer (score 1):

In oncreate add this,

```
    TextView need_an_account = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.need_an_account);
    need_an_account.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add OnClick to your xml to avoid using findViewById:

```
<TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:text="@string/need_an_account"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:onClick="textViewClick"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/need_an_account" />
```

and then write your function in the activity as:

```
public void textViewClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.need_an_account:
                // some code
                break;
        }
    }
```

no need to implement an OnClickListener if you dont want to define the TextView programatically. Remember to set TextView to clickable and for authenticity i also set background to ?selectableItemBackground so the user knows that the TextView can be clicked